# unexpected return (local jumperror)

Tags: ruby

```
def getPrime(testNumber)
    temp1=testNumber -1;
    bIsPrime = false;
    while (temp1 > 1) do
        bIsPrime = ((testNumber % temp1) == 0)  
        puts("Check 1 #{((testNumber % temp1) == 0)}, temp1=#{temp1} ");
        if ($bIsPrime) 
            break;
        else
            temp1 = temp1-1;
        end
    end
    return bIsPrime
end

puts("Enter any number to know if it's Prime or not");

testNumber = gets()

returnVal = getPrime(Integer(testNumber));

puts("Is enternered number Pime? #{return}");
```

I have just started with Ruby...So to begin with i tried to write a prime number program.

This thing is giving error "unexpected return"

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to upvote answers you find helpful. And be sure to "check" the answer that best answers your question.

Comment: you may want to look at Ruby's built in Prime library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although you already have your answer I thought it would be helpful to drop this here, it follows the same idea you're using in your code:

```
def is_prime?(test_number)
    (2..test_number-1).reverse_each do |i|
        divisible = (test_number % i == 0)
        puts "Check ##{test_number-i}, divisible=#{divisible}, temp=#{i}"
        return false if divisible
    end
    return true
end
puts "Enter any number to know if it's prime or not"
test_number = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Is entered number prime? #{is_prime?(test_number)}"
```

Comment: Thanks drep :) I was looking for your answer.. But i have other doubts as well on your answer... 1. "is_prime?" does adding a ? after the function name makes any difference?  2. What is the use of ## ?                        Thanks a lot for your reply :)

Comment: (1) Using ? at the end doesn't have any impact in the result, you can read more on this (and bang(!) methods) here:
http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/writing_own_ruby_methods.html  (2) the first # is just a normal string so it displays Check #1... Check #2.  One last thing, although I appreciate you picking my reply, mine wasn't really an answer but rather an addition so you could see how to write your code in a more ruby-like manner, should have picked Adam's or Larry's. If you can change it do so, otherwise keep it in mind for next time and glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

`return` is reserved. You cannot use it as a variable name, or otherwise, other than to return.

I believe you meant `puts("Is entered number prime? #{!returnVal}");`

Comment: Yes. Sorry i actually meant "${!returnVal}"

Answer (score 2):

Don't check this answer, Adam was first. But here's more info

As Adam says in his answer, the problem is that you said

```
puts("Is enternered number Pime? #{return}");
```

**What was happening**

Ruby evaluates whatever is inside the `#{ foo }` construct--if it is in an interpolated string, such as

`puts "1 + 1 = #{1+1}"` ==>> Will print  1 + 1 = 2

The resulting value is then converted (coerced) to be a string.

In your case, you told ruby to evaluate the `return` statement, which didn't make any sense in the context. Hence the slightly weird error message.